# Not receiving post data on node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a very simple node.js server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.post("/searcharea", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("SEARCH AREA2");
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send({ok:true});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3000")
});
```

However when I use curl and send data to the server I get an undefined as the req.body.  Here is my curl statement when testing.

```sh
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"
     --request POST   
     --data '{"username":"search":"here"}' 
     http://localhost:3000/searcharea
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about this data structure : `'{"username":"search":"here"}'`, but to ingest json data from an express server you are required to use the json middleware like this

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

//!Important
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/searcharea", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("SEARCH AREA2");
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send({ok:true});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3000")
});
```

Comment: This worked.  I dont really understand why I cant see the raw data sent but the middleware looks necessary.

Comment: @TommieJones Express works by chaining together middleware. The `app.use`  tells express that it should run what is inside `app.use` before each middleware that comes after `app.use`. That includes `app.post`. By default express wont try to parse what the request was. You can still see the actual request with the data even if you dont have the middleware if you inspect the req object. But if you put the middleware `json` in, it will try to parse the request and if the parsing was successful it will put the result into the body of the request object.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `req.body` will be undefined. You need to include some sort of [middleware to parse the incoming body](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body) of the POST request. Express.js packages this with it in v4.x and above. The included one handles most POST bodies but does not handle multipart requests. You'll need something like [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer) for that Change your code to this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// parse JSON request body
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/searcharea", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("SEARCH AREA2");
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send({ok:true});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 3000")
});
```